# setOnChildClickListener() receives viewholder instead of specific View clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, expandablelistview, android-viewholder

I've been researching the following issue for 2 days but to no vain. This is my first time posting here so please bear with me :)

Problem: My `setOnChildClickListener` (inside  an `Activity` with an `ExpandableListView`) receives a whole `ViewHolder` as the `View` parameter instead of the specific widget clicked. This leaves my `Activity` clueless as to what was clicked inside the `ViewHolder`.

In other words, `setOnChildClickListener` gets fired up if user clicks on any widget inside the item as long as the widget doesn't already have a `onclicklistener` setup in the adapter.

I'm using ViewHolder since it's advised for caching purposes. It's sitting in the `ExpandableListView` adapter and has a bunch of fields in it, like so:

```
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView image1;
    TextView tvImageNumber; 
    LinearLayout tvLayoverImage;

//and many more

}
```

My question is, how do I let my `Activity` know which exact element was clicked inside the `ViewHolder` so I could do specific things, like bring up a `Fragment`?

Notes:

1) My adapter is doing most of the work, including setting onclicklisteners for most of the views except this one
2) I want to do things this way to ensure my activity handles fragments, and not the adapter

I'll be happy to provide more details if necessary.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: View holders are over advertised, they give almost no benefit and are making your code misty

Comment: LaveKush, viewholder pattern helps speed up scrolling. It's apparently the prevalent opinion on SO and other sites I've scene. I could take it out if there is another way to avoid scroll-lag. Would you have a recommendation?